# How to disable logging with spark/scala project using gradle?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, gradle

I am using IntelliJ with gradle to build spark project. I tried multiple ways to disable logging but to no avail.

Here are some of the things that I have tried.
1. Add log4j.properties under src/main/resources with the following configuration

```html
# Set everything to be logged to the console
log4j.rootCategory=WARN, console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n

# Set the default spark-shell log level to WARN. When running the spark-shell, the
# log level for this class is used to overwrite the root logger's log level, so that
# the user can have different defaults for the shell and regular Spark apps.
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.Main=WARN


# Change this to set Spark log level
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark=WARN

# Silence akka remoting
log4j.logger.Remoting=WARN

# Ignore messages below warning level from Jetty, because it's a bit verbose
log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty=WARN


# Settings to quiet third party logs that are too verbose
log4j.logger.org.spark_project.jetty=WARN
log4j.logger.org.spark_project.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$exprTyper=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$SparkILoopInterpreter=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.parquet=ERROR
log4j.logger.parquet=ERROR

# SPARK-9183: Settings to avoid annoying messages when looking up nonexistent UDFs in SparkSQL with Hive support
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler=FATAL
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry=ERROR
```

2. Add these before and after sparkSession creation.

```html
Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF)
Logger.getLogger("spark").setLevel(Level.OFF)
LogManager.getRootLogger.setLevel(Level.OFF)
```

3. Add this when creating sparkSession

```html
val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
  .appName("test").master("local")
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("OFF")
```

I am running IntelliJ using mac OS, 
scalaVersion=2.11.8
sparkVersion=2.1.1

Help me please, I have looked up and down in the Internet and still can't find anything that works

Thanks a million!
May.

Comment: you found the solution for this.. I have same requirement

Comment: same here. I'm unable to turn off logs in my IDE. @user3426014,  Did you find the solution to this issue? Please let us know.

Comment: This worked after trying everything else

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27220196/disable-scalatest-logging-statements-when-running-tests-from-maven