# How to change log level in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, logging, log4j

I tried all this methods and nothing works :

In log4j file -

```
log4j.logger.org=OFF

log4j.rootCategory=ERROR, console
log4j.rootCategory=OFF, console
```

In code :

```
#option 1
Logger.getLogger("org.apache.spark").setLevel(Level.OFF)

#option 2
sparkContext.setLogLevel("OFF")

#option 3
val rootLogger: Logger = Logger.getRootLogger()
rootLogger.setLevel(Level.OFF)
```

And yes also tried by putting it after spark context object also before.Nothing seems working.
 What am I missing ? 
Or Is there another way to set the log levels ?

Answer (score 3):

You could find these logs from the start, which means we need to set log config via logback instead of log4j.

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/linzi/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/linzi/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.26/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.26.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
```

Add as logback.xml setting as below:

```
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>
            %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="com.mkyong" level="debug" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
</logger>

<root level="error">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should change your log level to OFF if you declare it before `SparkSession` object creation

```
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)

val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("test").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
```

Comment: No, it didn't work @Shankar Koirala, I tried it already by putting above the spark session

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it with something like this:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate();
spark.sparkContext().setLogLevel("OFF");
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#setLogLevel-java.lang.String-

Can you share the rest of the code and where you're running it?

Comment: sparkContext is not a callable, removing the parenthesis is needed. `spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("OFF");`